# How does the `use` method on Router instance of @koa/router work?

Tags: javascript, koa, koa2, koa-router

I have a very simple routing code using [`@koa/router`](https://github.com/koajs/router/blob/master/API.md):

```js
import Koa from 'koa';
import Router from '@koa/router';

const app = new Koa();

const router = new Router();

router.use('/api', (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = 'catch all with use';
  ctx.status = 201;
  next();
});


app.listen(3000);
```

However accessing the path `http://localhost:3000/api` returns 404. So, what is the exact use of `use` method of the router?

I wish to send all the request starting with `/api` prefix to a custom middleware which itself could be a `@koa/router` middleware or any other Koa middleware.

Comment: Can you also try to call http://localhost:3000/api// with a trailing slash ... I also had this problem ...

Comment: @SebastianHildebrandt Thanks for the comment. Already tried that and it failed. By default, the ending `/` get trimmed in most of the routing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to match everything under `/api/`:

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import Router from '@koa/router';

const app = new Koa();
const apiRouter = new Router();

const catchAll = new Router();
catchAll.get('/(.*)', async (ctx, next) => {
    console.log("Here is some middleware");
    console.log('/' + ctx.params[0]);
    await next();
    console.log(ctx.body)
}, async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.body = 'catch all with URL ' + ctx.url;
    ctx.status = 201;
    await next();
});

apiRouter.use('/api', catchAll.routes());
app.use(apiRouter.routes());
app.listen(3000);
```

This does not match `/api` without a trailing slash, though.

---

I found a simpler way to achieve the same. However, it does not use the `use` method of the router instance:

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import Router from '@koa/router';

const app = new Koa();
const apiRouter = new Router();

apiRouter.get('/api/(.*)', async (ctx, next) => {
    console.log("Here is some middleware");
    console.log('/' + ctx.params[0]);
    await next();
    console.log(ctx.body)
}, async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.body = 'catch all with URL ' + ctx.url;
    ctx.status = 201;
    await next();
});
app.use(apiRouter.routes());
app.listen(3000);
```

Notice how the second way's `'/api/.*'` is the first way's `'/api'` + `'/(.*)'`.

And apparently, the `use` of the router instance performs concatenation for the `get` paths (and similarly for `post` etc), so, if you used `(.*)` without leading slash for `catchAll.get` in the first way above, it would try to just concatenate it to `/api(.*)`, which then would match `/api2` and the likes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to update in your example

1. I recommend switching to use the [prefix option](https://github.com/koajs/router/blob/master/API.md#router-prefixes) from Koa/router. Then you do not need the path name in your `use` middleware

```
// this has `prefix` as an option now
const router = new Router({ prefix: '/api' });

router.use((ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = 'catch all with use';
  ctx.status = 201;
  next();
});
```

2. You must register the router with the app. the koa `app` does not know about the `apiRouter` in your example. you need to add this line before the `app.listen`:

```
app.use(apiRouter.routes());
```